# Conditional expectation with disjoint $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Let $(B^1,B^2)$ be independent Brownian motions with corresponding filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$. Let $\mathcal{F}^2_t$ be the filtration generated by $B^2$. How does one prove that for any $s<t$ and any $A$ measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}_s$, we have $\mathbb{E}\left[A\mid\mathcal{F}^2_s\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[A\mid\mathcal{F}^2_t\right]$?

This seems "intuitively" obvious, but I'm not sure to prove it formally. I think the issue is I don't know how to relate the disjoint $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{F}_s$ and $\mathcal{F}^2_t$.

Intuitively, the idea seems to be that $A$ can in principal be written in terms of $(B^1,B^2)$ up to time $s$. Because $B^2$ is a Brownian motion, observing its value over $(s,t]$ tells us nothing about $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Define $\mathcal I:=\left\{A_1\cap A_2,A_1\in\mathcal F_s^1,A_2\in\mathcal F_s^2\right\}$.

Then $\mathcal I$ is a $\pi$-system. Since the collection 
$$\left\{A\in\mathcal F_s,\mathbb E\left[A\mid\mathcal F_s^2\right]=\mathbb E\left[A\mid\mathcal F_t^2\right]\right\}  $$
is a $\lambda$-system which contains $\mathcal I$, we can conclude by the [$\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_system).

Comment: Nice answer. Do you think it might be worth expanding a little? E.g. eplaining why $\mathcal{I}$ is contained in your $\lambda$-system, explaining why it is a $\lambda$-system? It might also be worth pointing out that you can easily extend from simple random variables to any random variable in $L^1(\mathcal{F}_s)$.